# Redirect non-existing urls htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I need to make in my web site redirections of non-existent urls using htaccess.
I explain, You must redirect all urls to one that contains some word that you enter.
For example:
Two existing urls:

- https://www.example.com/this-is-a-house/
- https://www.example.com/my-dog-is-pretty/

So if I type in the search engine a made up url, for example: - https://www.example.com/adasd-asduasnd-house/ it redirects me to hhttps://www.example.com/this-is-a-house/ because it recognizes that there is a word that matches that url.
If I type https://www.example.com/asdj-dog-asdg-kjmfwds/ it redirects me to https://www.example.com/my-dog-is-pretty/.

If the url is https://example.com/jkasn-llcmbxk-djfdinjg/ it does not recognize any word so it redirects to home.

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Please do add your htaccess rules file in your question.

Comment: If this is a WordPress site then it's easy to do this using a Redirect plugin. With htaccess it can be done but you will need to write multiple lines of code to redirect your URLs one by one.

Comment: @AmitVerma Could you please tell me which plugin?